# Disabling extension per store

Tags: extensions, search

I'm wondering if I can disable an extension for a particular store?

I am developing on a Magento install that has several existing stores and my new store is inheriting an Auto Search Complete extension and hijacking the default Magento search.

If I disable this extension for that store in System > Configuration > Advanced then it removes the custom search but does not enable the default search.

If I disable the extension globally via app/etc/modules/Mirasvit_SearchAutocomplete.xml by changing

`<config>
    <modules>
        <Mirasvit_SearchAutocomplete>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </Mirasvit_SearchAutocomplete>
    </modules>
</config>`

to

```
<config>
<modules>
    <Mirasvit_SearchAutocomplete>
        <active>false</active>
        <codePool>local</codePool>
    </Mirasvit_SearchAutocomplete>
</modules>
```

then the default Magento search is reactivated (which is what I'm trying to achieve).

Can I do this only for my store view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the extension is using a layout update thru a xml file (in app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/) you can copy this file to your custom theme. Next remove the lines in the file so it becomes empty. This will give you the default search function instead again for only this store.

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you, this is exactly what I was looking for.